# Access 2013 form field value gets cut off on changing the number before the point

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Recently I created a form which loads some records from an SQL (linked) database.

I want to display some field values (which are decimal numbers - 30,2 in the sql server).

The values are loaded in the form and displayed with a comma for the decimals and a point as a 1000 separator like this: `5.222,55`. (Language settings on the computer).

Though the thing is, when I change the 5 before the point into any number then the value gets truncated and it sees the point as the decimal separator. So for example, if I only select the number 5 on the 5.222,55 number (so I leave the point) and then change it to a 2, the value is changed to `2,22`.

Though when I select the whole number or the first number AND the point then it changes correctly. So how can I get this right? The easy way is to just select the whole number on changing but I just want it to work in every way. Perhaps I can achieve it with VBA? I tried setting the format option (back in access 2000 I believe I could set the text field to long integer or currency or something but I cant find this in the access 2013 field properties).

**Additional information:**

- I am linking with a SQL server 2012,
- The linked table in Access sees the fields record source (the SQL fields) as short text (while they are decimals in the SQL server)

Comment: Which odbc driver do you use ? What is the version of your Sql Server ? When you open the linked table in design view, what does Access says about the data type ? There is an option is odbc to `Use regional settings when outputting currency, numbers, dates and times`. Did you try experimenting with that ?

Comment: SQL server 2012, the linked table sees the fields record source as short text (while they are decimals in the SQL server), no clue which ODBC driver I am using, where can I find that fast? Updates your questions in the main post as well!

Comment: Relink your table creating your own User DSN. See if it proposes SQL Server Native Client 11. If not you should install it. Anyway Access does not seem to recognize your numeric data as numeric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access cannot handle a 30,2 decimal, thus it is converted to text by teh ODBC driver.

So, either convert back and forth between text and numerics with `Str` and `Val` (the C* functions won't do), or change the data type of the field in SQL Server to, say, Money (= Currency in Access).