# Access linked tables truncating my Decimal values from the SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012, odbc

Since migrating the Access data to a SQL server I am having multiple problems with the decimal values. In my SQL tables on the SQL 2012 server I am using the Decimal data type for multiple fields. A while a go I first tried to set the decimal values to `18,2` but Access acted weird on this by truncating all the values (55,55 became 50 and so on).

So after multiple changes it seemed that Access accepted the `30,2 decimal` setting in the SQL server (now the values were linked correct in the linked Access tables).

A few days ago I stumbled however back on this problem because a user had problems with editing a number in the access form. So I checked the linked table data type and there it seemed that Access converts the `decimal 30,2` value to a `Short Text data type`, which is obviously wrong. So I did a bit of research and found out that Access cannot handle a `30,2 decimal`, thus it is converted to text by the ODBC driver. (See my previously post: [Access 2013 form field value gets cut off on changing the number before the point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172239/access-2013-form-field-value-gets-cut-off-on-changing-the-number-before-the-poin/33179007#33179007))

So to fix this latter error I tried, once again (forgetting that I already messed around with it) to change the decimal value to `17,2 / 18,2` and some other decimal values but on all these changes I am getting back to the truncating problem...

I found some posts about it but nothing concrete or answers on how to solve it.

Some additional information:

- Using a SQL 2012 server
- Using Access 2013
- Got a SQL Server Native Client 10 and 11 installed.
- Looking in the register key I found out that I am using ODBC driver version 02.50
- The SQL native client 11 has/uses DriverODBC ver 03.80 and the native client 10 uses DriverODBC ver 10.00 (not sure this is relevant though).

**UPDATE WITH IMAGES**

In a access form I have multiple lines that have a linked table (sql table) as record source. These lines get populated with the data in the SQL server. 
Below you can see a line with a specific example, the eenh. prijs is loaded from the linked (SQL) table.

[image]

Now when I change the 5 in front of the point (so making it 2555,00 instead of 5555,00) the value gets cut off:

[image]

======>>>

[image]

So I did research on it and understand that my SQL decimal 30,2 isn't accepted by Access. So I looked in my access linked table to see what kind of data type the field is:

[image]

So the specific column (CorStukPrijs) is in the SQL server a decimal 30,2 but here a short text (sorry for the dutch words). 
The other numerics (which are OK) are just normal integers by the way.

In my linked table on access - datasheet view the values look like this: 
[image]

I also added a decimal value of how it looks in my linked table:

[image]

In my SQL server the (same) data looks like this:
[image]

Though, because of the changing number problem before the point (back in the form - first images) I changed the decimal type of 30,2 in the server to 18,2. 
This is the result in the linked table on that same 5555 value:

[image]

It gives #Errors and the error message:

> Scaling of decimal values has resulted in truncated values

(translated it so wont be probably exactly like that in English)

The previous 0,71 value results with the decimal 18,2 in:

[image]

Hope its a bit clearer now! 
P.S. I just changed one decimal field to 18,2 now.

Comment: This is interesting. A while ago I was working on unit-tests for a C++ odbc-lib, and I tried to make the tests run against access. For numeric types I gave up - stating that Access is simply not able to work with numeric (decimal) values. So your only option would be to let the driver convert it to text and on writing let the driver convert the text back to a numeric-value.
If you always have two digits after the '.' you could try if access can work "better" if you set the type of that column to "Money" in Access. From my research, this is "like a decimal but with 2 digits".

Comment: Can you give a single concrete example of a value you're having problems with, and exactly what the problems are? And does everything work fine if you, for example, use a number format without a thousands separator in your Access front-end?

Comment: You wrote in your example: _the values (55,55 became 50 and so on)._
What are you using for decimal-separation? Comma like this   - 50,55 - or  point like this - 50.55 - ? In Germany for example, a comma is used, while in English you need a point. Have you considered that?

Comment: What happens if you launch Access, open the linked table in Datasheet View, and then edit the `Decimal(18,2)` column there? Does the decimal separator appear as a comma or a period? If you use that same separator when editing an existing value does the value get truncated? (I just tried that with my machine set to "French (Canada)" and `2,34` was accepted as a valid decimal value and was not truncated.)

Comment: @GordThompson Alright, so in datasheet view I have now the 18,2 decimal for 2 fields. In the SQL server I've got a value 0.71 when I look now in my access it is changed to 71. When I try to change the value back to 0.71 in my access linked table in datasheet view it makes of 0.71 --> 7100, when I change it with a comma (0,71) in the linked table it changes to 71. So it seems it just doesn't except the 2 decimal places. Machine language is Dutch, machine decimals are on 2 and separator is a comma.

Comment: @asdev Yep I have considered that. My separator is a comma on my machine, yet a point in the SQL server. Though it works with decimal 30,2 so I suppose, if it really was a comma/point problem the decimal 30,2 shouldn't work either..

Comment: @MattGibson Check my updates on the main post for a specific example and a bit clearer explanation.

Comment: After you changed the column definition in the SQL Server table did you drop and re-create the linked table in Access? If not, then try that. (Access caches certain information for ODBC linked tables.)

Comment: @GordThompson Yep, this didn't had any effect though. My tables are linked (and the current ones deleted) every time access is started up. A Macro for deleting the current ones and attaching them again runs with a macro that is executed from the autoexec.

Comment: @Nicolas: I just tested it on my machine - win7 en - it works: I created a new Table in SQL Server 2008 R2 that has one column ID (int) and one column (Decimal(30,2)) and filled it with some values. In Access, in a new Database I create a linked Table (using ODBC). I see the correct values and can edit them - the data in SQL Server is correct. My Access column looks exactly like yours on the screenshot.
But: This is all on one machine using the same locale settings. Can you try if things work if you run everything on the same machine? To indiciate if it is a problem of the '.' vs. the ',' ?

Comment: @erg Will give it a try! Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: Note the "longest" value I'm able to enter that works correctly in Access is is 123456789012345678901234567.25 : 27 Digits before the '.' and 2 after. 
If I enter something with 28 digits in front of the '.' and two digits after in SQL Server, Access will truncate the last digit after the '.'.
I guess this is because access will ask the driver to bind the column as text (SQL_C_WCHAR) and reserves only 'ColumnSize' chars, which would be 30 (not taking the char for the additional '.' into account).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently I found a solution for this problem! It all had to do with language settings after all.. (and the decimal 30,2 which is not accepted as a decimal in Access 2013).

I changed the Native client from 10 to 11 and in my connection string I added one vital value: `regional=no`. This fixed the problem!

So now my connection string is:
`szSQLConnectionString = "DRIVER=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;SERVER=" & szSQLServer & ";DATABASE=" & szSQLDatabase & ";UID=" & szSQLUsername & ";PWD=" & szSQLPassword & ";regional=no;Application Name=OPS-FE;MARS_Connection=yes;`"

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

No real good reason to try a decimal value of 30 digits?

Access only supports 28 digits for a packed decimal column. So going to 30 will force Access to see that value as a string.

If you keep the total digits below 28, then you should be ok.

You also left out what driver you are using. (legacy, or native 10 or native 11). However, all 3 should have no trouble with decimal.

As a few noted here, after ANY change to the sql table, you have to refresh the linked table else such changes will not show up.

There is NO need to have some re-link code every time on startup. And it not clear how your re-link code works. If the re-link code makes a copy of the tabledef object, and then re-instates the same tabledef then changes to the back end may well not show up.

I would suggest during testing, you DO NOT use your re-link routines, but simply right click on the given linked table and choose the linked table manager. Then click on the one table, and ok to refresh.

Also, in Access during this testing, dump (remove) any formatting you have in the table settings for testing (the format setting).

I suggest you start over, and take the original tables and re-up-size them again.

Access should and can handle the decimal types with ease, but it not clear what your original settings were. If the values never require more than 4 significant digits beyond the decimal, then I would consider using currency, but decimal should also work.

Comment: Wow positive feedback is not your strong suit is it. Nevertheless thank you for your feedback. The decimal value of 30 digits wasn't out of the blue, if you'd read the entire post you will find out why I chose that one. And like I also stated in my post why Access didn;t accept it for just the reason you stated (link provided. Your right on the client question, I am using Native Client 10. The re-linking mechanism first deletes all TableDefs (like I also mentioned). But sure I can give it a try to do it differently with testing. I'll also start it from scratch like you suggested.

Comment: @Albert: "Access should and can handle the decimal types with ease". This is IMHO not true. Access is unable to handle numeric values really, it cannot work something like SQL_C_NUMERIC_STRUCT internally. If an Access linked table connects to a Database using ODBC, it will always ask the database driver to read any Numeric column as SQL_C_WCHAR. So the driver will convert to / from text and map that to the representation of the databases numeric type.

Comment: Now you talking about ODBC and not Access then? The simple matter is that decimal types map just fine to Access and retain their data type AND ALSO their values when used with Access.  For any data type that Access cannot deal with then data type is returned as a string. In this case the data does NOT remain as string and thus who cares if the data is binary on disk, then goes to Africa and is read by some monkeys? At the end of the day Access has a LOGCAL view of the data as decimal type. So your point is NOT relevant UNLESS the data remained as a string in Access and it does not.

Comment: Sure, you did point out why 30 was used - I was pointing out that really was a guess and not a great idea.  Not a huge deal, I am just tying to save you future pain by suggesting better approach  to problem solving. A simple re-upload the data, re-link and you should be fine. You should not need to do anything else here - best of luck!

Comment: ODBC or not, Access simply has no support for decimal types. The only support for a decimal type in access is the money-type, which is a decimal with a fixed precision of 2. All other cases are resolved by defining a text column and then use some string-formatting of that column to make it behave like a decimal column.

Comment: @erg - Sorry, but you're wrong on two counts: **(1)** The "Currency" data type has a fixed *Scale* (number of decimal places) of 4, not 2. **(2)** "Decimal" values are stored in an Access database as numbers, not text. Your other comment is correct that Access ODBC does retrieve Decimal numbers as SQL_C_WCHAR, but Access itself stores Decimal values as 96-bit scaled numeric values. For example, the Decimal(18,5) value `3.14159` is stored in the Access database as `... 2F CB 04 ...` and 0x04CB2F is 314159.